# What is the purpose of this plastic strip of tape on some circuit boards?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I was cleaning an old mechanical keyboard from ~2013 the other day and noticed this strip of thick plastic tape covering a circuit on the smaller PCB that the power connector is wired into.  I have noticed this on other electronics before but I haven't been able to find a clear answer on why it's there and what it actually does.

Furthermore, is it important?  Can it be replaced?  The underside of the tape that isn't touching anything gathers dust and debris and can't be cleaned off very easily due to it being adhesive and everything.

Here is a poorly focused pic:

[image]

If it is important, is there a proper way to clean it or replace it?  If it isn't clear, I am not very familiar with PCBs or their functionality on a detailed level.

Comment: It may prevent from touching some parts of enclosure.

Comment: what plugs onto J4?

Comment: @jsotola This sits directly underneath the main PCB of the mechanical keyboard.  There is a steel plate on TOP with and the switches are mounted through it into the circuit board, but it's exposed on the bottom side.  All of the solder joins are one the bottom as well.  The pins go into a female equivalent to the J4 connector. 

Maybe the tape is to prevent it from touching areas it shouldn't?  It's quite thick and sturdy, and it seems quite well adhered to the surface.

Comment: @user263983 This part of the board doesn't come in contact with the enclosure, but the main part of the keyboard PCB.  It's what the pins connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tape was probably put there to provide a bit of protection from conductive dust/water drops causing shorts between the tight pitch pins of the IC it covers. This is a very unlikely failure/risk, so just yanking the tape off without replacement is fine. I've never seen such a solution so it is very much unnecessary and removable.

Comment: This does make sense, though I am concerned that maybe it's there to shield components from touching the PCB above it (The main keyboard PCB.  It has an input for the pins and the area where the power wires connect are just out of frame in the top left area)  It's quite hard to see what might touch.

I'm thinking I want to remove it, but replace it with something else just to be safe.  Is there anything particular I should or shouldn't use?  I would guess something that isn't conductive and made for use on PCBs, but that is pretty much a given.  Don't know much beyond that.

Comment: Even normal scotch tape will be fine, maybe 2 layers to be sure. One layer of black electrical tape will do great also. Both will give you short circuit protection and dirt protection. If you're happy with my answer above, click on the check mark 'accept answer' or whatever, it goes a long way with getting good answers out to people. Thanks and good luck!